# Como llamar a una corrutina dentro de una funcion que devuelve datos? kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, async-await, corrutinas

me encuentro manteniendo una app en donde tengo un esquema muy similar al que muestro en la imagen de abajo
[Esquema de clases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thHmM.png)

En el diagrama se puede ver que la clase "ClientClass" (es una clase escrita en Java) debe invocar un método Companion de la clase "ControllerClass". El código es el siguiente

```
public Client getClientDataByFirebase(){
    generation();
    Integer docNumber = ControllerClass.Companion.getDocNumber();

    ...

    return this;
}
```

El método "getDocNumber()" de la base "ControllerClass" (Escrita en kotlin - no pregunten porque, ya la recibí así) contiene lo siguiente

```
class ControllerClass{
   companion object {
      ...
      fun getDocNumber(): Int{
          //aqui había código que generaba un random
          //ahora debe consultar el valor de Firebase
          return DataEntity.getDataFromFirebase()
      }
   }
}
```

El método anterior antes generaba un random y lo devolvía, ahora debe consultar ese valor de firebase.
Ahora, esta porcion de codigo arroja un error puesto que un metodo "suspend" solo se puede llamar desde otro metodo "suspend" o desde una corrutina (scope).

El metodo en DataEntity es el siguiente:

```
suspend fun getDataFromFirebase(): Int {
        var docNumber: Int = 0
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            .child("docuNumber")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener {
                docNumber = it.value.toString().toInt()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                docNumber = 0
            }.await()
        return docNumber
    }
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente
Como hacer para que el metodo "getDocNumber()" de la clase "ControllerClass" pueda devolver el valor entero sin tener que convertirla en un "suspend" class.

Gracias

Comment: No se puede. Podrías retornar algún objeto observable pero no un `Int` directamente.  Aunque no tendría sentido convertir una API basada en callbacks a suspend functions para después volverla a convertir en callbacks. Tienes dos opciones razonables: migrar tu clase `ClientClass` a kotlin o directamente no usar suspend functions

Comment: Como te han dicho no se puede porque getDataFromFirebase sólo puede ser llamada desde una corrutina o desde una suspend function.  Si no usas suspend, deberás usar un CoroutineDispatcher pero ésto devuelve un job, no el Int.  Lo único que se me ocurre con lo que tienes es propagar el dato con un callback pero personalmente migraría el ClientClass e inyectaría las dependencias que necesiten: ClientClass necesita el ControllerClass y el ControllerClass necesita el DataEntity.  El DataEntity nedesita el FirebaseDatabase.